# Book recommendation for Atomic & Molecular physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, atomic-physics, education, molecules

What are some interesting books for a sophomore undergrad about Atomic & Molecular Physics?

Comment: Hello, check out this this thread: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/ it contains a load of book recommendations.

Comment: Didn't get any for atomic physics.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/

Comment: Hi user74219. Please don't repost a question in a new entry.

Comment: There was no answer for that question, so I reposted! Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Some good books on atomic physics are:

1. The classic "Atomic physics" by *Max born*.
2. Atomic Physics by *J Foot*.
3. The Feynman's lectures volumes.
4. Introductory Nuclear Physics by *K S Krane*.

Moreover there is a series of "very short introductions" books, those are good too for a pre insight on a subject of interest.

Answer (score 4):

A classic is [Bransden, Joachain - Physics of Atoms and Molecules](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/058235692X), a one-thousand tome covering a lot of basic material.

Another good book is [Atkins, Friedmann - Molecular quantum mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/058235692X). This one is at a slightly lower level than Bransden, and also contains reviews of basic concepts of quantum mechanics (it's pretty much self-contained). It has a lot of well done pictures and representations of the physical concepts.

Answer (score 2):

I think Linus Pauling's books would be a good place to look at. Although they are a little old, the exposition of the subject is outstanding and I think every beginning student of quantum mechanics should read them inorder to get a feeling of nature at work.

1. His book on [general chemistry](http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/0486656225/ref=pd_sim_14_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=0DEKZMTM3FC6Z9ATQ868)

This book are aimed at first year undergraduate students and explains the underlying principles of chemistry by unifying various branches of physics such as statistical mechanics, quantum mechanics etc.

2. Book on [quantum mechanics with applications to chemistry](http://www.amazon.in/Introduction-Quantum-Mechanics-Applications-Chemistry/dp/0486648710/ref=pd_rhf_dp_p_img_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=0MN7EH2YPPAAR14FJ6W0)

Here is a classic textbook by the ingenious chemist and he attempt to explain the nuances of the subject of quantum mechanics without assuming anything more than an elementary knowledge of differential equation. This book stands out for it's illustration of working principles of chemistry in terms of quantum physics. At least to my knowledge, I have not seen a better book on this aspect for a beginning student.