# Books on Atomic & Molecular Physics for beginners

Tags: resource-recommendations, atomic-physics, molecules

Some easygoing sophomore undergrad level books will go well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Book recommendation for atomic & molecular physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167562/)