# Textbooks for Dyslexics: Atomic Physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, atomic-physics

I am severely dyslexic (e.g. my reading ability is in the lowest 1st percentile) and as such I like textbooks with information clearly laid out and easily findable. An example of which is *Nuclear and Particle Physics* by W.S.C. Williams. To clarify I am looking for a book with (thanks to [knzhou](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310304/) for helping me clarify this):

1. Boxes with important results (both mathematical and not).
2. Definitions clearly labeled (e.g. in a box or like **Definition 1.2:**).
3. Examples clearly labeled etc.

I am in general looking for books on a range of subjects, but to prevent the question been closed as too broad here I am looking for books on **atomic physics**.

---

<sub>This question stems from [Books on Atomic Physics in the mathematical style?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/310304/books-on-atomic-physics-in-the-mathematical-style) which was more ambiguous then I had intended it to be and was (rightly) interpreted differently from what I had intended. This is the question I had intended to ask. It is probably worth pointing out that $\text{dyslexic } \ne  \text{ stupid}$ and book suggestions can still be very rigorous.</sub>

Comment: It sounds as though layout and visual style are as important if not more important than writing style. Do you find you need these things as cues to where to direct your focus? Would you put yourself in the bottom 1% in *technical reading*, or would you say your understanding is pretty much normal once you've decoded what words are there  (I'm suspecting this is so)? I'm asking these questions so that users may get a bit more insight into how your mind works and therefore suggest what may be helpful.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Let me try and describe how I think and learn. I learn through asking my self questions, e.g. What are Hund's rules? Why is the vector model valid?. I will only ever pick up a text book to find a direct and explicit answer to one of these questions - if I were to read a text book (even just a paragraph) I would not take the information in and I would be wasting my time.  Like you say I need cues to where to direct my focus. A book which has Hund's rules in the middle of a long paragraph is no good to me as I won't/can't read it. ...

Comment: ...If on the other hand the book has Hund's rules clearly labeled and in  a box this is much more useful to me. Like you hinted at once the information has been presented in such away my understanding of it is completely normal.

Answer (score 1):

These are not books but they are resources which can help you;

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-811-particle-physics-ii-fall-2005/

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-02-introduction-to-applied-nuclear-physics-spring-2012/

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-422-atomic-and-optical-physics-ii-spring-2013/video-lectures/lecture-1-introduction-to-atomic-physics/

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-101-applied-nuclear-physics-fall-2006/